# Qt deployment with websockets

Tags: qt, deployment, websocket

I have a small app which connects to an url by means of a QtWebsocket. The app works fine in debug and release mode. It downloads data from the website and updates it when new data available.

Now, after I deployed the app with windeployqt.exe, the app runs, but I don't receive data.

The websocket's signal "connected" is connected to the slot "onConnected" of MyClass, which handles the incoming data. I have been able to confirm that, when running the executable after deployment, the slot onConnected is not reached, and therefore no data is incoming.

I am in the dark, and have no idea of how debugging this, since the problem occurs only with the deployed application. I use the following config for the websocket (if this is of any help):

```
QSslConfiguration conf = m_webSocket.request().sslConfiguration();
conf.setPeerVerifyMode(QSslSocket::VerifyNone);
m_webSocket.setSslConfiguration(conf);
```

If someone has experienced the same issue, I'd be grateful if you share your knowledge. Otherwise, how could I get to the bottom of this? Some way to "debug"?

Comment: Did you check that the ports used are open?

Comment: @sirop No I have not. I will do so and update here, thanks. But if they weren't, the debug/release mode run from QtCreator wouldn't work neither would they? But they do behave as expected. It's just the deployed version.

Comment: I was able to check how QtCreator runs the app when hitting the play button. It includes some library paths the system PATH I was not aware of. The problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSL libraries were missing (ssleay and libelay). The app didn't crash, nor did dependence walker detect those dependencies.

Anyways, I hope this is useful for those who have the same issue.